# which sentence is correct (dry or dried)?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, past-perfect, past-participles

Which is right?

- The clothes are almost dry

or

- The clothes are almost dried

Context: I washed my clothes yesterday. Today, before it rained, I took the clothes in. The said clothes are not wet and not dry, somewhere in between. What should I say, if someone asked me?

Comment: Google 3grams show some evidence of the 'are almost dried' usage (though about half of theseseem to be false positives such as 'are almost dried up/out'). As Kate says, the adjectival usage is idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

The adjective *dry* seems the most natural. It would not be wrong to say they are almost *dried* and anyone would understand but it would seem unusual.